# Chrome extension: content policy complains about inline event handler and I can't find it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

Coding my first chrome extension and having some difficulty with the content policy. I keep getting inline event errors even though I removed the inline event I thought had caused the problem. Right now I'd just like to get this alert working. Here's the code minus irrelevant info.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
  <title>Placeholder popup</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    <label for="numWeeks">Nombre de semaines :</label>
    <input type="number" id="numWeeks" name="numWeeks"></input>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
var myAlert = function() {
  alert("Hello World!");
  //event listener for click of the button
  if (document.getElementById('submit') != null) {
     document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', myAlert);
  }
}
```

manifest.json:

```
{
   "background": {
     "persistant": false
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": ["some scripts, popus.js is not in this line],
   } ],
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
   "key": "placeholderPublicKey",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "__MSG_extName__",
   "options_ui": {
      "open_in_tab": true,
      "page": "description.html"
   },
   "version_name": "alpha0",
   "version":"1.0",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ ]
}
```

With this code I continue to see: "Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution." I removed an onclick() I had had before and thought that should have fixed the issue.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is it not giving you a line number? Are you injecting this in to a page with an inline script that isn't related to your extension that's causing the error?

Comment: If you see the error in `chrome://extensions` card, it's an old one, so simply clear it. Also you don't need `content_security_policy` in manifest.json.